# Lack of Data Node locality when working with S3 for HDFS - eventual consistency

Tags: apache-spark

Two points here after reading https://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/AmazonS3

1. Not sure what to make of this below.
   ...
   eventual consistency: changes made by one application (creation, updates and deletions) will not be visible until some undefined time.
    ...

Some undefined time? What does that mean for writing SPARK Applications then? If I have n JOBs, that may be something may not yet be visible?

2. How does the SPARK default partitioning apply then for S3 data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that Hadoop doc is a bit out of date; I'd google for "spark and object stores" to get some more up to date stuff.

The [spark documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cloud-integration.html) has some spark-specific details.

> Some undefined time? What does that mean for writing SPARK Applications then?

Good question. AWS never give the hard data here; the best empirical study is [Benchmarking Eventual Consistency: Lessons Learned from Long-Term Experimental Studies](http://www.aifb.kit.edu/images/8/8d/Ic2e2014.pdf)

That showed that consistency delays depend on total AWS load, and had some other patterns. Because its so variable, nobody dares give a good value of "undefined time".

My general expectations are

- Normally list inconsistency can take a few seconds, but under load it can get worse
- if nothing has actually gone wrong with S3 then a few minutes is enough for listing inconsistencies to be resolved.
- All the s3 connectors mimic rename by listing all files under a path, copying and deleting them, renaming a directory immediately after processes have written to them may miss data.
- Because the means by which Spark jobs commit their output to a filesystem depends on `rename()`,  *it is not safe to use them to commit the output of tasks*.

> If I have n JOBs, that may be something may not yet be visible?

It's worse than that. You can't rely on the rename operations within a single job to get it right.

It's why Amazon offer a consistent emrfs option using dynamoDB for listing consistency, and Hadoop 2.9+ have a feature, S3Guard, which uses dynamoDB for that same operation. Neither deal with update inconsistency though, which is why Hadoop 3.1's "S3A committers" default to generating unique filenames for new files.

If you are using the Apache S3A connector to commit work to S3 using the normal filesystem `FileOutputCommitter` then, without S3Guard, you are at risk of losing data.

Don't worry about chaining work; worry about that.

BTW: I don't know what Databricks do here. Ask them for the details.

> How does the SPARK default partitioning apply then for S3 data?

the partitioning is based on whatever blocksize the object store connector makes up. For example, for the s3a connector, its that of `fs.s3a.blocksize`

Comment: no worries: its an interesting problem which has kept myself and others busy. Look at https://github.com/steveloughran/zero-rename-committer/releases/download/tag_draft_003/a_zero_rename_committer.pdf